# How can I compute $\mathbb P\{T_n<T_0\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

Let $(X_n)_{n}$ a random walk over $\mathbb Z$ starting at $0$, i.e. $\mathbb P\{X_0=0\}=1$. I denote $T_k=\inf\{n\geq 1\mid X_n=k\}$. I suppose that $$\mathbb P\{X_{n+1}=X_n+1\mid X_n,...,X_0\}=p\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb P\{X_{n+1}=X_n-1\mid X_n,...,X_0\}=q.$$
Remark that $q=1-p$. How can I compute $\mathbb P\{T_n<T_0\}$, i.e. the probability to touch $n$ before touching $0$ ? In fact I have problem to interpret $\{T_n<T_0\}$ using $(X_n)_n$.

---

I tired as follow :

- $\mathbb P\{T_1<T_0\}=\mathbb P\{X_1=1\mid X_0=0\}=p$.
- $\mathbb P\{T_2<T_0\}=\mathbb P\{X_1=1\mid X_0=0\}+\mathbb P\{X_2=2\mid X_1=1\}=2p$
- $\mathbb P\{T_3<T_0\}=\mathbb P\{X_1=1\mid X_0=0\}+\mathbb P\{X_2=2\mid X_1=1\}+\mathbb P\{X_3=3\mid X_2=2\}+\mathbb P\{X_3=2\mid X_2=2\}(\mathbb P\{X_4=3\mid X_3=2\}+\mathbb P\{X_4=1\mid X_3=2\})$

I know that the last one is not clear at all, but I don't know how to interpret that fact that the walker can past many time between 1 and 2 many times before arriving at $3$.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The intepretation of $\{T_n>T_0\}$ is that the random walk touches first 0 and then n.

Comment: @quallenjäger: Indeed, I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: Consider the martingale $M_k=\frac12^{X_k}$ and the stopping times $$\tau_0 = \inf\{k>0: M_k=1\},\quad \tau_n = \inf\{k>0: M_k= 2^{-n}\}.$$

Comment: @Math1000: Sorry, but I don't really see in what it helps me in my problem.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of the biased random walk. In this case $\{X_k\}$ itself is a martingale, so let $$\tau = \inf\{k>0: X_k\in\{0,n\} $$ and use optional stopping to conclude that $\mathbb E[X_\tau]=0$. From there it is straightforward to compute $\mathbb P(X_\tau = n)$.

Comment: @Math1000: But I don't want to compute $\mathbb P\{X_{\tau}=n\}$ but $\mathbb P\{T_n<T_0\}$...

Comment: Same thing, different notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! For your three examples, I think you shouldn't condition on $X_0 =0$ because it does not change anything ($P(X_0=0)=1$). Instead we should condition on the value of $X_1$ (for $n\geq 2$) and use Bayesian formula. $P(T_1<T_0) = P(X_1 = 1) = p$ is obvious. For $T_2$, we have
$$
P(T_2<T_0) = P(T_2<T_0|X_1=1) \cdot P(X_1=1)+P(T_2<T_0|X_1=-1) \cdot P(X_1=-1).
$$ 
Since $P(T_2<T_0|X_1=1) = P(X_2=2|X_1=1) = p$, and $P(T_2<T_0|X_1=-1)=0$ (starting at $-1$, you must pass $0$ before arrive at $2$), we have $P(T_2<T_0) = p^2$.

For general $n>2$, we can still do
$$
P(T_n<T_0) = P(T_n<T_0|X_1=1) \cdot P(X_1=1)+P(T_n<T_0|X_1=-1) \cdot P(X_1=-1)
$$ 
and get $P(T_n<T_0) = P(T_n<T_0|X_1=1) \cdot P(X_1=1)$ because $P(T_n<T_0|X_1=-1) = 0$. So it remains to get $P(T_n<T_0|X_1=1)$.

Now it turns to a special case of the Gambler's ruin problem: we start at $1$, and we want to find the probability that we hit $n$ before hitting $0$. Doing a shift, it's equivalent to the probability that we start at $0$ and hit $n-1$ before hitting $-1$.

Thus by the [well-known result](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf) (see at the bottom of page 3) for Gambler's ruin problem, where $a = n-1$ and $b=1$ for our problem, we get
$$
P(T_n<T_0|X_1=1) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1-(q/p)^{n-1}}{1-(q/p)^{n}},\ p\neq 0.5\\
\frac{1}{n},\ p=0.5.
\end{cases}
$$ 
In conclusion, we have
$$
P(T_n<T_0) = P(T_n<T_0|X_1=1) \cdot P(X_1=1) = \begin{cases}
p\frac{1-(q/p)^{n-1}}{1-(q/p)^{n}},\ p\neq 0.5\\
\frac{1}{2n},\ p=0.5.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @Wanshan How can I show that $P(T_k < \infty)=1$.